# WebFlux: how to apply different set of WebFilters for different RestController

Tags: spring-webflux

Say I have 2 @RestController and a bunch of WebFilters.

Now I'd like to:

- Apply WebFitler A, B, C to controller X
- Apply WebFilter A, D, E, F to controller Y

How am I supposed to do that?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that; `WebFilter` is the equivalent of `ServletFilter`, so at that point, the request is not aware of the handler it's about to be dispatched to.

For use cases like this, a `@ControllerAdvice` is a better choice; you can apply it to a single controller, or all controllers in a package, or all controllers annotated with a specific annotation, etc.

Comment: ServletFilter can be config with mapping url patterns, right? Does WebFilter have similar capability?

Comment: not directly - but you can implement that in the webfilter method itself (to either apply it or skip it depending on the request URI)